# how to view FF image cache with thumbnail previews?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I'd like to browse through my Firefox cache to look for an image like I would a windows folder with thumbnails turned on. I found out about `about:cache`, but that gives me a list of keys and image names. I don't know what it was called, and I'm not willing to spend the time clicking on all the links (twice ) to view the images.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You probably meant `about:cache` instead of `about:config`.

Comment: You are right :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2489/) might work. I have never used it, it is only the first Google hit for "firefox cache browser".

(Note that tools like this make sense if your folder browser's preview feature depends on the file extensions. E.g. Nautilus or Konqueror show previews for any files that are images (determined directly from the file header), not matter what their names or extensions are (not sure if they are easily available for Windows though).)